# Read from stdin and store values into array C++

Tags: c++, stdin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a 2d char array to a 2d int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566856/how-to-convert-a-2d-char-array-to-a-2d-int-array)

I'm trying to read input from stdin and stop reading when encountering `EOF`. I need to store these values as integers in a 2x2 array, `array[i][j]`.

I'm reading in 81 Sudoku characters (integers) from a single line + 2 more characters (`\n` and `EOF`) for a total of 83.

Ex:

`STDIN -- > 123414292142341......2\n <EOF>`

How do I only store the numbers in each `array[i][j]`? and stop reading in when I encounter an `<EOF>` ?

So, after every 9 ints, I need to increment j to get the next row.

I'm looking to do this in C++

Thanks!

---

I have tried this so far

//Read in single line of 83 characters (81 sudoku integers + \n and 
//Store each integer into array of corresponding row and column

```
#include iostream

using namespace std;

string input_line;

int main()
{

  while(cin) {
    getline(cin, input_line);
  };


  return 0;
}
```

How do I tokenize the string "input_line" into a character of integers? and then to atoi to convert to int, and then finally store them in the Sudoku array??

---

OK, thanks almost done. but I now keep getting an invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' error!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

string input_line;

int main()
{

  char buffer[9][9];
  int sudoku[9][9];

  int v;

  cout << "Enter input: " << endl;

  cin >> (char*)buffer;

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                v = atoi(buffer[i][j]);
                sudoku[i][j] = v;
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: One of your classmates already asked about this yesterday: [How to convert a 2d char array to a 2d int array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566856/how-to-convert-a-2d-char-array-to-a-2d-int-array)  He also made a lot more progress before asking for help.

Comment: use cin.get() for extracting characters and storing as int....form a loop-in-a-loop structure to iterate through array ondices and above all try a bit harder insolving the problem cause its not the hardest problem out there...

Comment: @Tom: Your code is a mess.  You have a buffer overflow reading from `cin`.  Your attempt to assign into `sudoku[i][j]` is outside your loop, with the result that you try to access `sudoku[9][9]`, which doesn't exist (if it even compiles, which it won't with the new for scope rules).  You're trying to pass a character to `atoi` which requires a string.  Go study my answer to Phil's question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want in C++ then you may choose to use C++ style `cin`. Following is pseudo code:

```
cout<<"Enter input:\n";
char sudoku[9][9];
cin>>&sudoku[0][0];
```

Here we are taking advantage of the fact that any digit will be less than `< 256`. So your table will be arranged inside the `sudoku[][]` automatically.

Comment: That cast isn't valid.  Did you mean `&sudoku[0][0]`?

Comment: @Ben, this is valid case, I have checked in the g++ compiler. I am trying to leverage the fact that 2D array will be layed out as 1D array. Means `a[9][9]` is equivalent to `a[81]` in memory layout.

Comment: @iammlind: Regardless of what g++ does, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Who upvoted a buffer overflow?

Comment: @Ben, I have changed it. And there is **no buffer overflow**. If the user is **entering 81 characters** and pressing *enter* key. OP has clearly mentioned to enter 81 character. (though he assumes 2 more character which is not needed). Note that This will be used as 2D character array and not as a character buffer.

Comment: Where does the terminating NUL go, exactly?